# How do I turn off the LCD and EVF during timelapse on Olympus OM-D E-M1?

Tags: battery, timelapse, olympus-omd

I want to save as much battery as possible. EVF consumes a lot of energy. Is there any way to disable both displays during timelapse shooting?

Answer (score 2):

After reviewing the OM-D E-M1 user manual for firmware version 4.0, **there appears to be no way to turn off both the LCD and EVF**.